# Why won't my button delete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
document.getElementById("roster").innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"doSomething()\">+</button>\n" +
                                                    "<span onClick=\'$(this).remove();" +
                                                    "$(this).prev().remove();" +
                                                    "oiDelete(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                    "removeCost(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                    "selectedItem(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                    "frDelete(\"" + str + "\")\';>" +
                                                    str + "</span><br>";
```

So this goes inside a `Javascript` function I'm working on. What it's supposed to do is create clickable text regions (spans) that disappear when clicked as well as generate a button right before the clickable text that is supposed to be removed when the text is clicked. I can get the text to disappear just fine, but I can't get the darn button to go away.

The code being generated is:

```
<button onclick="doSomething()">+</button>
<span onclick="$(this).remove();
$(this).prev().remove();
oiDelete("Marneus Calgar");
removeCost("Marneus Calgar");
selectedItem("Marneus Calgar");
frDelete("Marneus Calgar")" ;="">Marneus Calgar</span>
```

Why is it generating `=""` at the end of the opening span tag? why is the button not deleting properly? is `$(this).prev().remove()` not the correct option?

Comment: First thing `$(this).prev().remove()` are all jQuery functionality. If you're not using jQuery (You haven't tagged your answer or mentioned it) then these functions will not work and the button won't be removed. As for the extra `;=""` try moving the single quote and the semicolon in this line here `"frDelete(\"" + str + "\")\';>"`. You want it to be `"frDelete(\"" + str + "\");'>"`

Comment: yikes on how you are building the button when you have jQuery available.

Comment: its in a big giant <script> block. i'm still fairly new to jquery. do i need to do something else besides slapping some <script> tags around jquery stuff?

Comment: Why is the click event not with the button? Seems weird to have it on the span.

Answer (score 2):

If we cast aside best practice, this is the working code.

```
document.getElementById("roster").innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"doSomething()\">+</button>\n" +
                                                "<span onClick=\'$(this).prev().remove();" +
                                                "$(this).remove();" +
                                                "oiDelete(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                "removeCost(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                "selectedItem(\"" + str + "\");" +
                                                "frDelete(\"" + str + "\")\'>" +
                                                str + "</span><br>";
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are removing the `span` which has onclick function on the fly. It means it can't reach the `$(this).prev().remove()` bit.

I hope it makes sense.

If you want to go an extra mile, you should put `$(this).remove();` after the `frDelete()` function. Otherwise those 4 functions that you call will never be called.

Comment: I don't see why this is casting aside best practice.  This is correct.  The function order must be switched.

Comment: @bowheart I would think it is because it's unreadable and unmaintainable to create HTML and JavaScript mixed together all in a single string.

Comment: There are many ways to Rome. I actually like putting together HTML and JavaScript together because it costs less than adding every single bit and pieces using jQuery. But I'm not sure if it is best practice. I just like cutting corners haha.

Comment: i admit, i'm not thrilled about how my code looks :( thank you for your suggestion, i'll try that out! i understand what you pointed out. makes sense now *facepalm*

Comment: @StephanusYanaputra Very true, and the code would probably be longer and more verbose. A benefit however would be that any developer who knows JS could come in and get a basic understanding of your code in a quick glance. The current code will be much less readable (even for @liz) 3 months down the track.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up quotation marks and of course - call self-remove code at the end (!)

And one tip - encapsulate these additional function in one procedure - it help to keep code cleaner.

```js
document.getElementById('roster').innerHTML += '<button onclick=\'doSomething()\'>+</button>' +
'<span onClick="doCalls(); $(this).prev().remove(); $(this).remove(); ">' + str + '</span><br>';
```

Comment: like the inline demo, where does it come from?